# Why can't i use the value that eval() returned to call the calculator function again and use the answer calculate something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, calculator, calc

I want to take the answer that was evaluated after using the calculator to perform more operations to it, but when I try using the answer variable into the `calc()` function it returns this error, `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not function`.

How can I have it where I can constantly take the answer and keep performing more operations with it? Also, I am having trouble figuring out how I can constantly use this calculator instead of the script just finishing after one calculation. What would be the best way to keep it running until I don't want it to otherwise?

```
# Calculates basic operations
def calc(x, op, y):
    if op in "+-*/":
        ans =  eval(str(x) + op + str(y))
        return ans

# Main function that controls the text-based calculator
def console_calculator():

    def user_input():
        while True:
            x = input('Type your first number: ')
            try:
                return int(x)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    return float(x)
                except ValueError: 
                    print('Please type in a number...')
        
    def operation_input():
        while True:
            operation = input('Type one of the following, "+ - * /": ')
            if operation in "+-*/":
                return operation
            else:
                print('Please type one of the following, "+ - * /"...')
             

    answer = calc(user_input(), operation_input(), user_input())
    print(answer)

    print(calc(str(answer), operation_input, user_input)) # This line of code throws the error

console_calculator()
```

Comment: You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: You don't need `eval` at all; you've already gone to the trouble of validating the operands as valid numbers, and validating the operator separately, so you can simply map the operation to an appropriate function; the `operator` module makes this easy.

Comment: For example: `{'+': operator.add, '*': operator.mul, ...}[operator](user_input(), user_input())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try using the answer variable into the calc() function it returns this error, "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not function".

When you pass a function without parenthesis like argument, you are passing **the function object** and not the value returned by the the function.

```
 print(calc(str(answer), operation_input(), user_input()))
```